# Why Stripe API is not working on live website?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe to handle some payments on a little website.

In local, everything works great : all my tests are good.
The problem is in live website : I can get a token (from javascript) but the `\Stripe\Charge::create` in the php side is buggy and I can't figure out why.

Here's some infos :

```
# Making Stripe works
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/stripe/init.php');

# Set API Key (Both Live and Test keys don't work)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_****");

# Trying to charge
# $token is defined from the $_POST and works great ($amount and $metas are fine too)

try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
        array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'source' => $token,
            'metadata' => $metas
        )
    );

    // Blabla
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // Catching card error
} catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
    // Catching RateLimit API error
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    // Catching invalid request (missing param or else)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
    // Catching fail authentification from API KEY for example
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
    // Catching fail APIConnection
    // The error seems related to this because the catch is done here !
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    // Catching base error
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Catching other errors
}
```

On local it works great, but on live server it catches an error (after a while) on the `\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection` with no real informations.

```
#$e contains :
"httpStatus":null,
"httpBody":null,
"jsonBody":null,
"httpHeaders":null,
"requestId":null,
"stripeCode":null
```

Which is not a very good sign.

Except for the gettin' token part (which works great) I have nothing in my Stripe's Dashboard's Logs about this Charge Trial. It looks like Stripe never receive the request.

I tryied to ping `api.stripe.com` from my server, it works great.

Code on local and live sites are the same, stripe keys are well copy/pasted (it works on local, so...).

My Stripe's account is validate so I can use Live Keys (but both live and test keys are not working like I said).

API is up-to-date.

I don't know where else to search : I contacted the Stripe's support and I'm still waiting for an answer.

Thx for your interest...

Comment: Put `print_r( $e );` in every catch statement and then try to process the payment. You will see the related errors, if any.

Comment: if it works sometimes (as your text suggests), you may have a rate limit exception, or some kind of outbound https connection failure related to your hosting environment.  just a wag.

Comment: @RahulDev the print_r happens in the catch \Stripe\Error\ApiConnection as i mentionned, but contains just `null` values... 
@YvesLeBorg it only works on local (and it ALWAYS works on local) but never in live website... About the https connection failure, what should I check ? 
Thx guys

Comment: @Vae your host may be blocking either the port or the target IP addy.  If you are on AWS, or some other competent cloud provider, ***you*** may be blocking these by not having enabled appropriate policies for your virtual service. Also ... `after a while` seems to suggest a DNS resolution error (and fallback, usually takes 5 seconds typically).  Verify that the target host name is resolvable inside your hosted server.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg agreed, I think it does not reach Stripe server... On my server, `ping api.stripe.com` works and `dig api.stripe.com` too. BTW I triple-checked : Port 80 and 443 are open.

Comment: dig uses an external resource (ie not DNS), but since ping works your DNS is resolving.  Also, ping is ICMP (not TCP), so pinging works does mean https working.  Finally, did you check **outbound** port and IP for TCP protocols (like http/https) ? Lastly , Stripe could be blackholing your host , and refuse connections for some reason. After you are certain that packets fly outbound, you may have to check with Stripe.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I'm sorry, both of my english and my server-skills are not that good. I'm gonna learn how to take care about this "outbound" you're talking about, and I'll keep you in touch

Comment: tip : try to do a curl to Stripe (either command line of a throwaway php script), where you enable verbose mode, and if php where you can look at curl_getinfo.  If curl_getinfo shows that 0 bytes have been sent, the problem is on your hosting, if not you have an issue with Stripe , in which the verbosity of curl will tell you much more about what is happening.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Well, I tried this :
`> curl -v https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_test_mykey:`, got : `* About to connect() to api.stripe.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 52.25.214.31...
* Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` ... Sounds like something is wrong if my hosting but what :o

Comment: (And the curl_getinfo() via php gives me an array full of empty values, of course...)

Comment: that means the packets are not leaving your hosting environment.

Comment: Ok so two noobs questions about that : #1 How is it possible when I can easily get a token from Stripe with javascript ? #2 How the hell should I fix this X_X (Thx a lot for your help :) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166145/discussion-between-yvesleborg-and-vae).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a looong talk with @YvesLeBorg (thanks man) and a lot of researchs, I was finally able to make all this work by adding this to my iptables'rules file :

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

From what I understood, it allows any locally originating traffic. As you can see, I'm not very expert in those things so if someone thinks it's wrong (even if it's the only thing that made all this works), please tell me.

Comment: I had the same issue on my localhost instead, after reading all the chat and trying to figure out how my local server was blocking the request, I found this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102311/6225838) which basically said to add this before the calls: `Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);`. It basically disables security certificate checks.

Comment: @CPHPython Thx for your answer ! I'm not very certain that disabling SSLCertificates would be a good idea haha. But it's a way to go :) Thx !

Comment: indeed, it's not a good idea. My issue in the end was due to the [**ca-certificates.crt** file (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044059/6225838) that was not properly referenced.